# Making Array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am looking for some urgent help with jquery , i have some input boxes and i want so retrieve their value as an array, the problem is that all the input boxes will be created dynamically with an add more button, so i am not sure how many of they would be, my code to create dynamic boxes is here.

```
$(function(){
x = 0;
$('#addmore a').live("click",function(){
    x++;
    $('#addmore').append('<input type="text" id="fname_' + x + '"/></p>');      
    return false;
});
```

});

now let say a person clicked addmore for 3 times now i will have 3 inputboxes with #fname_1, #fname_2 and #fname_3. now i want all the 3 values inside an array.

Thanks

Comment: add a class name to the input elements and query that

Comment: How is PHP related to that problem?

Comment: Please try to keep confusion to a minimum ...

Comment: @felix ... sorry dude that was a mistake and question is now edited

Comment: @ esailija :- can you be more descriptive

Comment: @kevin, I put it in my answer below

Comment: `$('#addmore a').live("click",` - sounds like a job for event delegation... `$( '#addmore' ).delegate( 'a', 'click', ...`

Answer (score 1):

Add `name` attribute like this:

```
$(function(){
x = 0;
$('#addmore a').live("click",function(){
    x++;
    $('#addmore').append('<input type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname_' + x + '"/></p>');      
    return false;
});

});
```

When you submit, you will have `$_POST['fname']`, which hold array of your auto-generated input boxes.

By the way, are you sure that you need to put `</p>` after each input?!

Comment: yeah that is required so i have some styles on <p></p> otherwise my form will ugly

Comment: @kevin, the start tag `<p>` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without adding anything (name or class) with such code:

```
var values = $.map($("#addmore input[id^='fname_']"), function(element, index) {
    return element.value;
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/X3jnx/).

This will iterate over all inputs with `id` starting with "fname_" and map their value into single array.

Comment: Context please: `$( 'input[id^="fname_"]', '#addmore' )`. (Doing a page-level query for INPUT elements is not efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

If this has nothing to do with php:

```
$(function(){
x = 0;
$('#addmore a').live("click",function(){
    x++; //Add "text-field" class 
    $('#addmore').append('<input type="text" class="text-field" id="fname_' + x + '"/></p>');      
    return false;
});

});


function getFieldValues(){
var r = [];
//Query text field class and push the values into an array
    jQuery( ".text-field").each(
        function(){
        r.push( this.value );
        }

    );

return r; //returns an array with the values
}
```

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yeah $ would do here as it's clear it's mapped to jQuery. I always use jQuery out of (good?) habit, since in the wild there are gazillion libraries using $ :P

Comment: For jQuery code inside the DOM-ready handler (which is where all jQuery code should be anyways), you can use this trick to get the `$` name safely: `jQuery( function ( $ ) { ... });`. [Read here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) under section "Aliasing the jQuery Namespace".

Comment: It has nothing to do with namespacing but to make it instantly clear to a reader that a piece of code uses jQuery. Also, most of my code is in "class" declarations where it doesn't make any sense to have it in document ready handler.